# Asm.js support in Script#

Tags: script#, asm.js

Would it be practical to add asm.js support to Script#?

Where would effort be required?

Answer (score 2):

This would be quite interesting - the right place for this discussion is really over on the script# github repository itself (https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp).

I haven't looked at all the details of what entails constraining to the asm.js model, but I'd be interested in helping out with the effort. We can plug in different code/script generators - the input to the generator is a model of the code, and the generator can produce script to a subset of javascript. I believe the effort will be reasonable once there is good understanding of the asm.js subset.

We'd also want to modify ss.js (the script runtime) to conform to the asm.js subset.

Hope to see you open this on github and taking the discussion further and possibly even contributing :)